# Error in scraping https://www.nytimes.com.how do I solve it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer, infinite-scroll

I am trying to scrape https://www.nytimes.com using pupeteer library in nodejs using below code.But it is giving error thar document is undefined.How do I scrape all data using infinte scrolling successfully.???

```
static async listenNewsUpdate()
    {
   
        ScrapeModel.browser = await puppeteer.launch({
          headless: false,
        });
        const page = await ScrapeModel.browser.newPage();
        await page.goto(ScrapeModel.websiteURL);
        await page.evaluate(() => new Promise((resolve) => {             
          var scrollTop = -1;
          const interval = setInterval(() => {
            window.scrollBy(0, 100);
            if(document.documentElement.scrollTop !== scrollTop) {
              scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
              return;
            }
            clearInterval(interval);
            resolve();
          }, 10);
        }).
        then())
        var posts=document.body.querySelectorAll('article')
     
        var postItems=[];    
        posts.forEach((item)=>{

            try{
              title=item.querySelector('h2').innerText;
              link=item.querySelector('a').href;
              summery=item.querySelector('p').innerText;
              postItems.push({
                'title': title,
                'links': link,
                'summery': summery
              })
            }catch(e){

            }
        })
      
        await ScrapeModel.browser.close();
      
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, 'document' is not defined in your code. When writing the callback for page.evaluate(), the 'document' objects exists in the scope because the puppeteer's evaluate() defined it for you.

So your first and second references to 'document' are inside the evaluate() callback and are ok. But your third reference is outside of the callback, where 'document' is no longer in the scope.

Comment: Can u refactor the code for me??
bcz I cant get the  posts result out of this scope....Everytime it is giving me null.... :)